# How to use Multiple forms in one Csharp panel in one Windows Form panel?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am building a kids learning application, where clicking on a button on panel, I want to show different forms in the same place of the panel. Can you please help with any walk-through or tutorial links?

Comment: Posts that need direct coding help should be posted at stackoverflow. This vertical is for professional discussions on software development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question should have been posted on Stackoverflow website rather than here.

But you can use this approach to handle the case.

```
            subForm = new SubFormYouWantToLoad();
            subForm.TopLevel = false;
            subForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            ContainerPanel.Controls.Add(subForm , 0, 1);
            subForm .Visible = true;
```

You can add this code when you click on the specific button.
Here each subform is added to the Panel as a Control. You should remove the subform from the panel's control list before adding another subform. For this ,it is better to remove,close and dispose the first one.

```
        ContainerPanel.Controls.Remove(activeform);
        activeform.Close();
        activeform.Dispose();
```

Comment: Your answer is not a good solution and is misleading. You shouldn't add a Top-Level control to a control.

Comment: @Vimal Raj subForm Controls are not showing in panel except blank Window

Answer (score 5):

Instead of Forms use user controls and load them in to panels

Sample if you want to show usercontrol1

```
panel1.Controls.Clear();
panel1.Visible = true;
UserControl1 usr1 = new UserControl1();
usr1.Show();
panel1.Controls.Add(usr1);
```

If usercontrol2

```
panel1.Controls.Clear();
panel1.Visible = true;
UserControl1 usr2 = new UserControl2();
usr2.Show();
panel1.Controls.Add(usr2);
```

Comment: After Showing the form in the panel of another form it is not closing .. I I use ActiveForm.Close(); then it is closing the main application. What I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: What you want to close post the code you have written in the question

Answer (score 0):

You could create a number of forms as user controls or a control that inheriets from a panel. Then have a parent form with a panel to hold the user controls. You can then change the active user control in the container when the panel needs to be changed.

There is a tutorial on msdn for creating user controls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to close the form on the panel but not worked..

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dontShowPANEL();
        //ActiveForm.Close();
        MainImaginCp kj = new MainImaginCp();
       //kj.Visible = false;
        kj.panel2.Controls.Clear();
        panel1.Visible = true;
        EngABCLearning usr1 = new EngABCLearning();
        usr1.Show();
        kj.panel2.Controls.Add(usr1); 
        //kj.Focus();
    }
```

And I used the following code to show the form in the panel.

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_LR_ENG_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //kids.Form2 hj = new kids.Form2();
        //hj.Show();


        EngABCLearning gh = new EngABCLearning();
        //gh.Show();
        gh.TopLevel = false;
        gh.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        //Panel2.Controls.Add(subForm, 0, 1);
        panel2.Controls.Add(gh);
        gh.Visible = true;
    }
```

This is closing my main form and exiting the application.

Answer (score 0):

try this out i have loaded two forms inside a single panel

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f1 = new Form2();
        f1.TopLevel = false;
        f1.AutoScroll = true;
        panel1.Controls.Add(f1);
        f1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
        f1.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        f1.Show();
        //form2
        Form3 f2 = new Form3();
        f2.TopLevel = false;
        f2.AutoScroll = true;
        panel1.Controls.Add(f2);
        f2.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
        f2.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        f2.Show();



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this i used this method to load multiple forms at one panel

```
private Form activeForm = null;

public void FormLoad(Form childForm)
    {
        if (activeForm != null)
        {
            activeForm.Close();
        }

        activeForm = childForm;
        childForm.TopLevel = false;
        childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        panelName.Controls.Add(childForm);
        childForm.Visible = true;
    }
private void YourBtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormLoad(new youWantToLoadForm1Name());
    }
private void YourBtn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormLoad(new youWantToLoadForm2Name());
    }
```