# DataGridView button column buttons looks disabled after loading to panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I created two win forms with two DataGridViews. For each grid view data filled in the form_load event of each form.
Then I created a master form with two vertical panels. In left side panel there are two buttons and according each to button click, above two forms are loading in to right side panel.

So far everything works fine. But  buttons in the each grid view not looks as usual buttons in the forms. those buttons looks disable. no change onclick.  but if I run above two forms without master form, buttons looks fine.

[image]
[image: Main form with two buttons]

Comment: How do you show up your forms?

Comment: Please look at above second image. when user click on the bitton1, first form add in to pnlCanvas. when user click the button2, then clean all the forms in pnlCanvas and adding second form.

Comment: You're adding a form to a panel? I haven't seen using the forms this way before, I think you should use UserControls or MDI Forms for such cases.

Comment: @VahidND: see this post, I used this method, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594971/how-to-use-multiple-forms-in-one-csharp-panel-in-one-windows-form-panel

Comment: If you read other comments and answers on that post you'll see that's not a clean solution and people have problem using it so I'm considering voting that answer down. I suggest following another answer on that post which suggests using UserControls instead of Forms.

Comment: @VahidND: +1 thank you so much for your time and guide. I solved the issue using UserControl instead of Child forms. Now everything works fine. Thank you again =)